# Dynamic Comments in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet named "OPL" . I have Types in `column B` which is a drop down list. And by a lookup formulae I have already calculated there Number of hours and stored it in `column P`. Now I Need to add the values in `Column P` as the comments to the `B`. I have a code which does that as I want. But the Problem is I Need to run the macro everytime I add a new Type into the list. I want this to happen Dynamically i.e. As soon as I add a new Type, It should automatically take ist respective value from `column P` and make it a comment. I know that I Need to add this code in the Worksheet code by Setting the `Target` but somehow I am unable to implement it.

```
Public Sub addComment()

    Dim row As Integer
    Dim oldComment As String

    'Set start row
    row = 6

    With Sheets("OPL")

        'Do until "B" cell is blank
        Do While .Range("B" & row) <> ""

            'If "P" cell is not blank
            If .Range("P" & row) <> "" Then


                'Insert comment for "A" with old if exist
                .Range("B" & row).addComment ("Dauer : " & .Range("P" & row).Value)

            End If

            'Increase row
            row = row + 1

        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automate this to the level of attaching or changing comments when values in columns B or P change you will need a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B,P:P"), Range("6:1048576")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim bp As Range
        For Each bp In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B,P:P"), Range("6:1048576"))
            Range("B" & bp.Row).ClearComments
            If Not IsEmpty(Cells(bp.Row, "B")) And CBool(Len(Cells(bp.Row, "P").Value)) Then
                Range("B" & bp.Row).AddComment _
                  Text:="Dauer : " & Range("P" & bp.Row).Value
            End If
        Next bp
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

That should survive pasting or clearing multiple values in columns B and/or P.

Comment: thanks for the help. I was also trying to do something similar, the Approach Looks fine to me but somehow nothing happens after the application of this code. I also tried to debug by placing a `msgbox "comin here"` just after the first If Condition which means that whenever I Change a value in Column B then the Message should appear. But unfortunately it doesnt

Comment: a) this belongs in a worksheet's code sheet, not a module code sheet b) it only adds a comment if there are values in columns B and P, the target (changed cell) is in row 6 or greater, I've tested it and it worked well for both adding and removing values.

Comment: I am calculating the values of Column P by a VLookup based on the values of column B. Which means that, as soon as I select a new Type, I will then get a corresponding value in Column P . The values in column P are not pre stored So Is this a Problem of dynamic calculation or something ? @Jeeped

Comment: no. while a formula does not trigger a worksheet_change, changing the value in column B would. i still suspect that you put it in the wrong place since you have not confirmed that you put it into the worksheet's code sheet.

Comment: ok ok...I guess I figured out whats Happening. The Debugging works when a value in `column P` is changed. But It should happen the other way round. Do I Need to swap the ranges ?

Comment: Tried to fix It but still the comment does not appear.

Comment: If you have formulas in column P then they will never be 'empty'. I've adjusted the code above. See the [sample workbook](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Dynamic%20Comments%20in%20Excel.xlsb).

Comment: Perhaps you have crashed with enableevents = false. Put `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the VBE's Immediate window and hit [enter] then try again.

Comment: Yes. It works perfectly in your sample workbook. I am just wondering what could be the Problem ?

Comment: I'm afraid I do not have an answer. Unless it is the enableevents environment variable or simply a corrupt VBA environment, I cannot even speculate.

Comment: Is it related to the enableevents because I also have alot of code already behind the same worksheet ?

Comment: Yes it could be. EnableEvents must be True in order to trigger the Worksheet_Change. That's exactly why we turn them off; so changing something inside the Worksheet_Change doesn't trigger it again.

Comment: I found another strange Thing. When I Change the value in `column P`, then the `column B` has the right comment while it should happen the other way round. Could you think what could be the possible Problem ? Also I have a list to Chose from in the `column B`. But I dont think so that is a Problem.

Comment: Or to be more precise, after Debugging I found that it is only detecting changes in the `column P` and not in `column B`

Comment: I found out the Problem. The already present code in the worksheet was already searching for `column B` adn if found then `Exit Sub` . So this code could not detect any Change in `column B`. I just placed this code above the old code and it works. Thanks alot for the help.